# How to return an int value stuck in a for loop but a callback in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to get the size of this firebase collection size of documents, and for some reason in Kotlin, I can't seem to get this to work. I have declared a variable to be zero in an int function and I put it inside a for loop where it increments to the size of the range. Then when I return the value, it is zero. Here is the code I have provided, please help me as to why it is returning zero.

This is just what is being passed to the function

```
var postSize = 0
```

That is the global variable, now for below

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
getPostSize(first)
```

This is the function

```
private fun getPostSize(first: Query){
   first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
      for(document in documents) {
       Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
       getActualPostSize(postSize++)
   }
 }
return postSize
}

private fun getActualPostSize(sizeOfPost: Int): Int {
// The number does push to what I am expecting right here if I called a print statement
      return sizeOfPost // However here it just returns it to be zero again. Why @tenffour04? Why? 
}
```

It is my understanding, according to the other question that this was linked to, that I was suppose to do something like this.

Comment: is your logger actually logging multiple entries?

Comment: I believe so. I mean if I print the postsize inside that for loop, it actually gives me the appropriate numbers. The size is 10, but when I return it, it goes back to 0, from where I initialized it. See this is not an issue in java, but in Kotlin, well lets just say Kotlin likes to be complicated.

Comment: This doesn’t have to do with the for loop. You are incrementing the variable in a callback. The callback is called some time in the future after this function has already returned.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Well sir, how could I fix that? So I can actually get the value?

Comment: I linked your question to one that explains the different options for how to handle it.

Comment: How to handle what? I'm talking about an Int, that is an integer. I'm not interested in an API. That is something different. @Tenfour04

Comment: How to handle getting a result from an API. Firebase is an API. `addOnSuccessListener` is adding an asynchronous callback that retrieves a result from the API. The result you want is the count of something returned in the asynchronous callback. That’s just a detail. Your first problem is learning how to handle asynchronous code as explained in the link. Once you understand that, counting something in the callback is trivial.

Comment: @Tenfour04 how man? How? By creating another function to callback to? It is so blank inside those answers. So confusing. It don't got the answers!

Comment: @Tenfour04 I see four different functions there. You're saying I need four different functions for this to work?

Comment: The section starting with “How do you do this for Kotlin” explains how to make your function take a callback parameter. In your case the `YourReturnType` would be an  `Int`. In your success listener, you would call this callback parameter with the count value. Then below that it explains how to call this function you’ve created and respond to the future result, inside the lambda. The alternative to using callbacks and asynchronous code is to use coroutines. But that takes a lot more explanation than can fit here. The Kotlin documentation has a lot on the subject.

Comment: So the -> unit is not suppose to mean anything or is it? I'm so confused by the explanation I'm sorry. I'm new to Kotlin, I'm new to firebase. This is so different for me to comprehend. I see 4-5 different functions with the same name just different in the inside. I just don't know what the beep is going on.

Comment: @Tenfour04 This would've been a lot easier if it didn't get duplicated and was answered so I could understand it. So the people who search this could understand this. So everyone could understand this.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so "callback(bar)" is essentially suppose to be "foo(callback)" correct? Well then I see another supposedly "previously called" foo where it is just saying "foo() { result -> which is essentially "whatever operation I previously wanted to do"  }  well sir, the operation was already done in the for loop with the documents. What other operation would need to be done?

Comment: `-> Unit` means the callback doesn’t have to return anything. In your case, `getPostSize()` won’t care what the code that calls it does with the result so it doesn’t need a value back from the callback. Anyway, if you are completely new to higher order functions in Kotlin, what I would do for now until you get used to it is eliminate `getPostSize()` function completely and move its contents to the place you are calling it from. Then understand that the code in the listener is called in the future so if you want a count, do it inside the listener and use that value inside the listener.

Comment: @Tenfour04 let me update my question so you can see how I interpreted that question and put it in my code/program

Comment: @Tenfour04 so my function shouldn't be returning anything? And well, it is being called from the addOnSuccessListener{}, which I for some reason, can't seem to comprehend how a callback will be from the future? When it is happening right there and then...

Comment: @Tenfour04 do you see a clear and simple answer to my question up above? I don't. I am still trying to comprehend this.

Comment: Okay, after a bit of more thoroughly reading, I changed up the method a bit, however I get an error with my get()... why? @Tenfour04 it says I have an "unresolved reference" with get().....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question has answers that explain how to approach getting results from asynchronous APIs, like you're trying to do.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-return-an-empty-or-null-value)

Here is a more detailed explanation using your specific example since you were having trouble adapting the answer from there.

Suppose this is your original code you were trying to make work:

```
// In your "calling code" (inside onCreate() or some click listener):
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
val postSize = getPostSize(first)
// do something with postSize

// Elsewhere in your class:
private fun getPostSize(first: Query): Int {
    var postSize = 0
    first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
       for(document in documents) {
           Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
           postSize++
       }
    }
    return postSize
}
```

The reason this doesn't work is that the code inside your `addOnSuccessListener` is called some time in the future, after `getPostSize()` has already returned.

The reason asynchronous code is called in the future is because it takes a long time to do its action, but it's bad to wait for it on the calling thread because it will freeze your UI and make the whole phone unresponsive. So the time-consuming action is done in the background on another thread, which allows the calling code to continue doing what it's doing and finish immediately so it doesn't freeze the UI. When the time-consuming action is finally finished, only then is its callback/lambda code executed.

A simple retrieval from Firebase like this likely takes less than half a second, but this is still too much time to freeze the UI, because it would make the phone seem janky. Half a second in the future is still in the future compared to the code that is called underneath and outside the lambda.

For the sake of simplifying the below examples, let's simplify your original function to avoid using the for loop, since it was unnecessary:

```
private fun getPostSize(first: Query): Int {
    var postSize = 0
    first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
       postSize = documents.count()
    }
    return postSize
}
```

The following are multiple distinct approaches for working with asynchronous code. You only have to pick one. You don't have to do all of them.

**1. Make your function take a callback instead of returning a value.**

Change you function into a [higher order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html). Since the function doesn't directly return the post size, it is a good convention to put "Async" in the function name. What this function does now is call the callback to pass it the value you wanted to retrieve. It will be called in the future when the listener has been called.

```
private fun getPostSizeAsync(first: Query, callback: (Int) -> Unit) {
    first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
       val postSize = documents.count()
       callback(postSize)
    }
}
```

Then to use your function in your "calling code", you must use the retrieved value inside the callback, which can be defined using a lambda:

```
// In your "calling code" (inside onCreate() or some click listener):
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
getPostSizeAsync(first) { postSize ->
    // do something with postSize inside the lambda here
}
// Don't try to do something with postSize after the lambda here. Code under
// here is called before the code inside the lambda because the lambda is called
// some time in the future.
```

**2. Handle the response directly in the calling code.**

You might have noticed in the above solution 1, you are really just creating an intermediate callback step, because you already have to deal with the callback lambda passed to `addOnSuccessListener`. You could eliminate the `getPostSize` function completely and just deal with callbacks at once place in your code. I wouldn't normally recommend this because it violates the DRY principle and the principle of avoiding dealing with multiple levels of abstraction in a single function. However, it may be better to start this way until you better grasp the concept of asynchronous code.

It would look like this:

```
// In your "calling code" (inside onCreate() or some click listener):
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
   val postSize = documents.count()
   // do something with postSize inside the lambda here
}
// Don't try to do something with postSize after the lambda here. Code under
// here is called before the code inside the lambda because the lambda is called
// some time in the future.
```

**3. Put the result in a LiveData. Observe the LiveData separately.**

You can create a LiveData that will update its observers about results when it gets them. This may not be a good fit for certain situations, because it would get really complicated if you had to turn observers on and off for your particular logic flow. I think it is probably a bad solution for your code because you might have different queries you want to pass to this function, so it wouldn't really make sense to have it keep publishing its results to the same LiveData, because the observers wouldn't know which query the latest `postSize` is related to.

But here is how it could be done.

```
private val postSizeLiveData = MutableLiveData<Int>()

// Function name changed "get" to "fetch" to reflect it doesn't return
// anything but simply initiates a fetch operation:
private fun fetchPostSize(query: Query) {
    first.get().addOnSuccessListener { documents -> 
       postSize.value = documents.count()
    }
}

// In your "calling code" (inside onCreate() or some click listener):
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
fetchPostSize(first)
postSizeLiveData.observer(this) { postSize ->
    // Do something with postSize inside this observer that will
    // be called some time in the future.
}
// Don't try to do something with postSize after the lambda here. Code under
// here is called before the code inside the lambda because the lambda is called
// some time in the future.
```

**4. Use a suspend function and coroutine.**

Coroutines allow you to write synchronous code without blocking the calling thread. After you learn to use coroutines, they lead to simpler code because there's less nesting of asynchronous callback lambdas. If you look at option 1, it will become very complicated if you need to call more than one asynchronous function in a row to get the results you want, for example if you needed to use `postSize` to decide what to retrieve from Firebase next. You would have to call another callback-based higher-order function inside the lambda of your first higher-order function call, nesting the future code inside other future code. (This is nicknamed "callback hell".) To write a synchronous coroutine, you `launch` a coroutine from `lifecycleScope` (or `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` in a Fragment or `viewModelScope` in a ViewModel). You can convert your getter function into a `suspend` function to allow it to be used synchronously without a callback when called from a coroutine. Firebase provides an `await()` suspend function that can be used to wait for the result synchronously if you're in a coroutine. (Note that more properly, you should use `try/catch` when you call `await()` because it's possible Firebase fails to retrieve the documents. But I skipped that for simplicity since you weren't bothering to handle the possible failure with an error listener in your original code.)

```
private suspend fun getPostSize(first: Query): Int {
    return first.get().await().count()
}

// In your "calling code" (inside onCreate() or some click listener):
lifecycleScope.launch {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val first = db.collection("Post").orderBy("timestamp")
    val postSize = getPostSize(first)
    // do something with postSize
}
// Code under here will run before the coroutine finishes so 
// typically, you launch coroutines and do all your work inside them.
```

Coroutines are the common way to do this in Kotlin, but they are a complex topic to learn for a newcomer. I recommend you start with one of the first two solutions until you are much more comfortable with Kotlin and higher order functions.

Comment: I'm not sure about your unresolved reference for `get()` in your modified code, as I don't use Firebase myself. I don't see any differences between your original code and modified code that would introduce the problem because you are calling `get()` on the same function parameter as before.

Comment: What do you mean by " do something with postSize, if you said immediately after not to do something with it?

Comment: You can use it inside the lambda, but not after/outside the lambda.

Comment: What am I suppose to do inside there? Increment the post size? I'm not quite sure what is suppose to be going on inside there. Like a function?

Comment: You use the postSize value for whatever you were going to do with it. It already is the full count of your documents. It’s ready to use at that point for whatever you want.

Comment: Well I want to use that value to pass it onto another button.setOnClickListener { },  to set a limit on something with an if statement, but I can't seem to store that value at all..

Comment: Also, am I suppose to have two functions of getPostSize()? or just one, which is the async one? What would I do with the other one if I'm suppose to be having two?

Comment: Delete the old function and replace it with the async one. If you need to use the retrieved value inside a click listener, then you have to create the click listener that uses it inside the callback, because the value is not available except inside the callback. Since the button cannot be used until after the value arrives in the callback, you might want to set the initial state of that button to be disabled or invisible, and then set it enabled or visible inside the callback where you also give it a click listener.